# Выборка связанных записей yii2

Tags: yii2, rest, activerecord, связывание-данных

Знаю, что вопрос избитый, но тем не менее разобраться все никак не могу, второй день мучаюсь.
Есть таблицы Projects и Projects_img. Они связаны так:

**модель Projects**

```
public function getProjImgs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProjImg::className(), ['projectId' => 'id']);
    }
```

**модель ProjImgs**

```
 public function getProject()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Project::className(), ['id' => 'projectId']);
    }
```

Необходимо что бы при обращении к REST контроллеру ProjectsController выводились данные в следующем виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал делать выборку через with :

```
 $project = new Project();

 return $project->find()->with('projImgs')->all();
```

Реакции никакой. Данные выводятся без массива изображений:

```
    {
        "id": 210,
        "name": "Новостройка",
        "client": null,
        "description": "Спасибо!!",
        "date": "2021-05-01 20:04:36",
        "price": 4000000,
        "time": "4 месяца",
        "square": 46,
        "category": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 259,
        "name": "TEEST",
        "client": "",
        "description": "",
        "date": "2021-05-11 09:43:40",
        "price": null,
        "time": "",
        "square": null,
        "category": 1
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добиться результата? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Должно работать. Только если некорректно связь прописана...например ошибка в колонке `['projectId' => 'id']` .  А может на серваке то всё нормально а вот на клиенте что-то не то?  А если `asArray()` делать то что?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, помог asArray(). Это очень странно и не логично, я считаю, почему в объекте не указываются связи?

Comment: Не могу подсказать. Наверное потому, что эти связи работают через магические методы php и они видны при print_r. Однако при пересыле на клиент - клиент ничего не знает о связях и берет только главный массив объектов. В общем думаю что тут просто проблема в магии yii2 и магических методах на которых он работает.

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/rest-resources#fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Алексею Шиманскому, действительно, связанные данные почему то отображаются, только когда выводятся как массив. Т.е. что бы вывести связанные данные необходимо использовать asArray().